# Mac - Open a .pro file with with Qt

Tags: qt, qmake

I am trying to utilize the magread program, [found here](https://github.com/ieatlint/MagRead), but when I try to open the .pro file from the finder I get: "The operation can’t be completed because the original item for “magread.pro” can’t be found.".  Qt (full disclosure I have no experience with this program, just found out when I tried to run magread) is installed fully and correctly, and won't even recognize the file.  Also, it is also suggested to build the project using qmake in the terminal, but I get an error saying that the command isn't found.  If anyone knows how to properly implement either solution to get this thing up and running would be very appreciated.

Comment: Use Qt Creator or find the Qt command prompt, where right qmake is in PATH. If you have neither, you do not have properly installed Qt SDK.

Comment: Also, to be clear, .pro file is just text file, it is a project file for *qmake* for building a project (actually for creating Makefiles, which is what *qmake* does, the building is done by *make*).

Answer (score 0):

As you've probably identified by now, the program uses the Qt framework, which provides, amongst other tools, the qmake program to build the magread project.

You need to install Qt, which you can read about [here](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.1/qtdoc/gettingstarted.html), before building the magread project

Answer (score 0):

`qmake` isn't a command that your system will recognise immediately as under OS X it installs into your `/Users/` directory. If you've done the full Qt installer it'll be something like `/Users/Alexander/Qt/Qt5.1/clang_64/bin/qmake` (or thereabouts), so you can run it from the command line at that stage, however if you run Qt Creator you should be able to load the `.pro` file and build from within there.